# scrapy recursive callback with time

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to scrape a website which scrapes information of given webpages every 5 minutes. I implemented this by adding a sleep time of 5 minutes in between a recursive callback, like so:

```
    def _parse(self, response):

        status_loader = ItemLoader(Status())

        # perform parsing        

        yield status_loader.load_item()


        time.sleep(5)
        yield scrapy.Request(response._url,callback=self._parse,dont_filter=True,meta=response.meta)
```

However, adding time.sleep(5) to the scraper seems to mess with the inner workings of scrapy. For some reason scrapy does send out the request, but the yield items are not (or rarely) outputted to the given output file.

I was thinking it has to do with the request prioritization of scrapy, which might prioritize sending a new request over yielding the scraped items. Could this be the case? I tried to edit the settings to go from a depth-first queue to a breadth-first queue. This did not solve the problem.

How would I go about scraping a website at a given interval, let's say 5 minutes?

Comment: how about recursively re-run the spider file?

Comment: good idea, I will try that instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work because `Scrapy` is asynchronous by default.

Try to set a corn job like this instead -

```
import logging
import subprocess
import sys
import time

import schedule


def subprocess_cmd(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    proc_stdout = process.communicate()[0].strip()
    logging.info(proc_stdout)


def cron_run_win():
    # print('start scraping... ####')
    logging.info('start scraping... ####')
    subprocess_cmd('scrapy crawl <spider_name>')


def cron_run_linux():
    # print('start scraping... ####')
    logging.info('start scraping... ####') 
    subprocess_cmd('scrapy crawl <spider_name>')


def cron_run():
    if 'win' in sys.platform:
        cron_run_win()
        schedule.every(5).minutes.do(cron_run_win)

    elif 'linux' in sys.platform:
        cron_run_linux()
        schedule.every(5).minutes.do(cron_run_linux)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


cron_run()
```

This will run your desired spider every 5 mins depending on the `os` you are using

Comment: This work perfectly, way better than using scrapy's CrawlerRunner() class in my experience.

Comment: Glad to know, I use this approach frequently